# How do I run a function once a day when other functions run with fixed interval multiple times a day

Tags: python, scheduler

I have a constantly running code using [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/), and there is a place in the code that needs to run once a day.

#### Code

The code is defined as a nested function.

Small presentation about code:

```
def main():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def errorTable():
            ...
            ...
    file_read.close()

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
        schedule.every(1).seconds.do(main)
    except:
     time.sleep(1)
```

The `main` function performs an operation approximately every 2 minutes. However, I want the `errorTable` function in it to run only once a day.

#### Issue

Since the code has a certain processing time, I cannot run it according to datetime. Because time can be missed. When I give a range, the code can run more than once.

Other than all that, is there a way I can run the code once a day?

Comment: You could use threading or multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see an issue in your code. It seems that every second you create a new job. I do not think that this is correct. Try to do this:

```py
def main():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    def errorTable():
            ...
            ...
    file_read.close()


schedule.every(1).seconds.do(main)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Second, it seems that you would like to process exceptions (if they happen in your function). The [schedule documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/exception-handling.html) recommends to use a wrapper:

```py
import functools

def catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=False):
    def catch_exceptions_decorator(job_func):
        @functools.wraps(job_func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return job_func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                import traceback
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                if cancel_on_failure:
                    return schedule.CancelJob
        return wrapper
    return catch_exceptions_decorator
```

Regarding your question, I think it's worth to extract the function that you would like to run once a day and schedule it as well:

```py
@catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=False)
def main():
    ...
    ...
    file_read.close()

@catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=False)
def errorTable():
    ...
    ...

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(main)
schedule.every(1).day.at("00:00").do(errorTable)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand the logic better. However, there is one thing I am wondering about. The main function can take up to 2 minutes to complete. What if the code that takes 2 minutes is still running during the 00:00 time I set? Does the other code not work?

Comment: Then, it is required to look at the implementation of the schedule library. Try to read the documentation and there should be written how the scheduling works (if it makes a queue with tasks or other approach) and if it is thread and multiprocess safe.